# Intersection with open set

Tags: general-topology

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are both open sets then their intersection is still open;

my question is, can we say the same thing when we know that only $A$ is open and $B$ is an arbitrary set? Intuitively, if $x\in A\cap B$ then in particular $x\in A$ so there is an $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq A$ so shouldn't it be possible to find an $r'>0$ (smaller than $r$) such that $B(x,r')$ is also a subset of B?

Comment: No.  For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $(0,2) \cap [1, 3] = [1,2)$, which is not open.

Comment: But it *is* true that $A\cap B$ is open in the subspace $B$ (with the topology it inherits from whatever space in which $A$ and $B$ originally lie).

Comment: "so shouldn't it be possible to find an r′>0 (smaller than r) such that B(x,r′) is also a subset of B?"  If so, that would be true whether or not you intersected B with A or not.  And x can be any point of B.  That would mean B has to be open.  If B isn't open.  if $x \in B$ is not an interior point of B.  And $x \in A \cap B$, that can't be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology. Then $(-1,1)$ is open, but $(-1,1)\cap\{0\}$ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Think about it.  If $B$ isn't open  then there is a point of $B$ that is not an interior point of $B$.  If that point is in $A\cap B$ it can't be an interior point $B$ so it would not be an interior point of $A \cap B \subset B$.  (If there is no neighborhood $B(r,x) \subset B$ we cant have $B(r,x)\subset A\cap B \subset B$.)

> in particular x∈A so there is an r>0 such that B(x,r)⊆A so shouldn't it be possible to find an r′>0 (smaller than r) such that B(x,r′) is also a subset of B

Only if $x$ is also an interior point of $B$.  If $x$ is a boundary or isolated point of $B$ that is obviously not true.

Basic counter example:  $A = (-1,1)$ and $B=[0, 2]$ then $A\cap B = [0,1)$ is obviously not open

Oh, even more obvious.  Let $B \subset A$.  Then $B \subset A = B$.  This would imply all subsets of open sets are open.  Obviously not true as all sets are a subset of some larger open set (the entire space for example).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of an open subset $A$  is that when $x\in A$ then all points "very close" to $x$ also lie in $A.$ In a metric space, with a distance-function (metric) $d$, this means that, for some $r>0,$ every $y$ for which $d(y,x)<r$ will also  belong to $A.$ But  if $B$ is not open, then there exists $x\in B$ such that for every $r>0$ there exists $z\not\in B$ with $d(z,x)\leq r.$ Then no subset of $B,$ such as $B\cap A$, that contains $x$, can be an open set.

The definition of a topology is very general. Not all topologies can be described by metrics or open balls. Strictly speaking, a topological space is a pair $(S,T)$ where $T$ is a collection of some or all of the subsets of $S,$ such that

(1). $S\in T$ and $\phi\in T.$

(2). The common intersection of any $finite$ collection of members of $T$ belongs to $T.$

(3). The common union of $any$ collection of members of $T$ belongs to $T.$

$T$ is called a topology on $S$  and the members of T are called open sets (or "open with respect to $T$").

It is common practice to speak of "the space $S$" even though it is incorrect usage.

If the intersection of any open set $A$ with any arbitrary  set $B$ were open then every subset of $S$ would be open, because $A$ could be $S$ and $B$ could be any subset of $S.$ If $T$ is the set of all subsets of $S$ then $T$  $is$ a topology, called the discrete topology on $S$. But if $S$ has more than one member then there are other topologies on $S.$

The smallest space not describable by a metric is Sierpinski space: $S=\{1,2\}$ and $T= \{S,\phi,\{1\}\}.$ In a metric space,  if $d(1,2)=e\ne 0,$ then the open ball $B_d(2,e/2)$ (which is an open set) contains the point $2$ and not the point $1.$ But in Sierpinski space there is no open set containing $2$ but not containing $1.$